# Giving error while creating partial class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am developing MVC application in which , I am trying to create the partial class of class generated by MVC application lets say Location class.

Now I want to create the partial class of Location class in new class file.

The below class code is auto genrated by MVC of Location code.

```
namespace CRM
{
    public partial class Location
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Remark { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have added new class file which contain the partial class of above file

```
namespace CRMEntities.Partial_Class
{
    public interface ILocation
    {
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Region can accept maximum 50 characters.")]
        string Region { get; set; }

        [Key]
        int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        string Name { get; set; }

        string Remark { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Location : ILocation
    {
    }
}
```

**Its giving the below error... 
`CRMEntities.Partial_Class.Location' does not implement interface member 'CRMEntities.Partial_Class.ILocation.Name`**

Answer (score 3):

First, you don't need to do this, what I understand is you are trying to do validation right? Think about, the object generated by EF is not ViewModel, they are domain model. Data annotation should be in View Model, not domain model.

Most of cases, often mis-use is to use domain model as view model, but it is not correct much. Because sometime, view models need more than one domain model to provide data for your UI.

So for separation of concerns, you need to define your View Model different with domain model.
Example: you have Location class, you need to add LocationViewModel class and put data annotation in here.

You can map manually or use [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) for mapping bettween View Model and Domain Model.
Another solution is you can use [Fluent Validation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/), with this way, needless to have more partial class just for validation.

Comment: Hey, thanks, Can You please tell me the steps how to do that ? I am doing this first time.

Comment: You need to create View Model separately with model generated by EF. Then, take a look: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61629/AutoMapper how to map View Model to Model. Then, But valiation on View Model

Answer (score 1):

You don't show the definition of `ILocation` in your question, but the error says that the `Location.Name` property is declared differently than the `ILocation.Name` member.

**Edit:** Your two partial classes appear to be in two different namespaces, hence they are actually two entirely different classes, not two parts of the same class. That would explain the compiler error.

Having said that, I do agree with the other answer (+1!) that you should do your UI validation on a view model instead.